Springboot＋Mybatis＋PostgreSQLでSELECTした結果に引数として渡したEntityのデータの一部を追加したい
Springboot＋Mybatisを利用しています。
事前にSELECTしていた結果をListで保有しているのですが、
この結果をもとに別テーブルでSELECTした結果にEntityAのデータを一部入れたいです。
EntityA
    int id
    int key
    int dataA
    …

テーブルA
    id、key、…

BMappaer.java
public interface BMapper{
    List<EntityB> findByEntityA(@Param("entityAList") List<EntityA>entityAList);
}

Mapper.xml
<select id="findByEntityA" parameterType=""jp.co.xxxx.EntityA" resultMap="jp.co.xxxx.EntityB">
    SELECT *
    FROM テーブルA
    WHERE (id, key)
    IN
    (
        <foreach collection="entityAList" item="entityA" separator=",">
            (#{entityA.id},#{entityA.key})
        </foreach>
    )
</select>

上記で、テーブルAの抽出はできるのですが、EntityAのもつ、dataAをSELECT結果に追加したいです。
引数の値をSELECTに追加することは可能でしょうか？

良く分かりませんが、結果を取得した後、Java のコードで設定した方が良さそうです。
dataA が別のテーブルのデータとして存在するなら、JOIN して取得する方法もあると思いますが。

ありがとうございます。Javaコードで設定することはできました！
